# Sockets between pages?

Tags: c#, html, .net, sockets, asynchronous

I have **Page A**; clicking on a link, I open a **Page B** (in the same domain) as popup.

Popup make some operations.

When these operations finish, I'd like to update some divs of the **Page A**.

What's the best strategies? There is no `ajax` call/callback. I guess chat working like this? Can you suggest to me such a strategy? A sort of sockets?

Comment: Why would you need to use the server? There is a parent child relationship!

Comment: Why would you need to touch sockets?

Comment: I don't know? That's why I opened this question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer is for JavaScript:

In the child page you can use `var parent = window.opener` to get a reference to the parent. In the parent window you can access the child by `var child = window.open(/*..*/);`

You can call functions directly if they are in the global scope or you can set up a message passing system with `window.postMessage()`.

Comment: `You can call functions directly if they are in the global scope` how can I assicure this? I have the control of both, so I can manage the whole context. Same scope of? Javascript? Can you give to me an example such as "hello world"?

Comment: You could mention `returnValue`.

Comment: The global scope is the `window`. If you define a function in the global scope you can access it via `window.my_func()`. @AshBurlaczenko I don't know what you mean.

Comment: But .. what? You don't need `.returnValue` you already have a reference to the window.

Comment: The problem now is that on Server side before load the Popup, I do the redirect! I don't know if I can store the parent reference...

Comment: You can't pass references, so: nope.